# error occurred loading file: package:core_elements/src/common.dart

Tags: dart, core-elements

I am using Dart Dev 1.7.0_03, polymer 0.14.2+1, core_elements 02.2+1 and paper_elements 0.2.0.

Attepting to run my application compiles successfully, but the index.html page is not displayed. The index.html in the console shows the following:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/packages/core_elements/src/common.dart
An error occurred loading file: package:core_elements/src/common.dart
```

There is no other output. Looking at the packages I do not see this resource either.

I get this result on both the DartEditor and the eclipse dart-editor plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At first you should try to restart `pub serve` then

```
pub cache repair
```

If it doesn't solve the problem it might be a bug in the package.

Comment: Hi Gunter, Restarting the DartEditor does not help. How do I execute the commands you mentioned above? Where in the dart-editor folder do I find them? Thanks

Comment: You should add `darteditor/dart-sdk/bin` to your path then the `pub` command can be found on the command line. `darteditor` is the Dart install directory (at least on my Linux system).

Comment: After a `pub update` just now, to get the latest web_components (which fixes Polymer not working on iOS8), I too have this error.

Comment: sorry everyone, this was a subtle problem with breaking changes and choosing the right version for core and paper elements. We decided to release a new version of paper 0.2.1 that should now fix the issue. Technically this is the same as version 0.3.0+1, but we decided to rerelease it as 0.2.1 because that will unbreak most people more easily. Simply `pub upgrade` once more to get the latest fixes

Comment: Thanks Siggi! That resolved it for me. :) (Post as official answer?)